# Identric mean is less than arithmetic mean

Tags: inequality, means

I'm doing a paper work about theory of means and their inequalities and I'm trying to prove that if A denotes the arithmetic mean and I the [identric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identric_mean) then
$$
 I(x, y) \le A(x, y)
$$
for $x,y>0$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{e}\left(\frac{y^y}{x^x}\right)^{\frac1{y-x}} \leq\frac{x+y}{2} \, .
\end{equation}

Every article I have researched send me to this one:
https://www--tandfonline--com.uma.debiblio.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0025570X.1975.11976447
where it is supposed to be proved, but that has to be payed for.

Comment: Obviously false: If $x,y>0$ are very small then $x^x$ and $y^y$ are both close to $1$, so the LHS is close to $1/e$ while the RHS is close to $0$.

Comment: It is not false, actually it is a famous result from Stolarsky, in your argument what happens with $(...)^{\frac{1}{y-x}}$

Comment: I don't know what $(...)^{\frac1{x+y}}$ you're talking about. The inequality you stated _is_ false. It could be you stated the famous result incorrectly

Comment: Oh, now I see it. The notation $\sqrt[x+y]{\frac{x^x}{y^y}}$ is an incredibly bad choice - the $x+y$ was literally invisible the first five times I looked (I couldn't change my downvote until the post was edited, so I cleaned it up for you.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: It seems that you replaced the $(y-x)$-th root by the exponent $1/(x+y)$.

Comment: i imagine i did - i can't see the difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We must assume that $x \ne y$ because the left-hand side is not defined for $x=y$. Then we can assume that $x<y$ because both sides not change if $x$ and $y$ are exchanged.

Taking logarithms, we need to show that for $0 < x < y$
$$
\frac{y \ln y - x\ln x}{y-x} - 1 \le \ln \left( \frac{x+y}{2}\right) \, .
$$
Using an idea from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2354994/42969) to a related question we write the left-hand side as an integral:
$$
 \frac{1}{y-x}\int_x^y \ln(t) \, dt  \le \ln \left( \frac{x+y}{2}\right) \, .
$$
And this is true because the logarithm is a *concave* function.

Comment: thank you. The reason why logarithm being a concave function implies that inequality is a famous result?. I know that the hermite-hadamard inequality looks alike but for convex functions

Comment: @pedro: It *is* the Hermite–Hadamard inequality (or Jensen's inequality if you prefer). For concave functions the inequalities are just the other way around.

Comment: @pedro: You can also “see”
 it if you draw a graph of the logarithm and of its tangent line at the point $(x+y)/2$.